# Using ADO connection to Sharepoint when excuting SQL query [Created By] column outputs Number and not Name

Tags: 2010

So the question is around how to change [Modified By] column is SQL select line so that internal field indexes off Default ID(number) and gives Name.  I would expect something like: [Modified By].xxxxx.name.  Hope this clears up my issue.

```
Set recs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Set iplDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

  iplDB.Open _
       "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;Password=;User ID=; " & _           
    "DATABASE=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/; LIST={xxxxxxxxxxxxx}; " 

  command1 = "Select L.Reticle_ID, L.Created, L.Modified, L.[Created By], L.[Modified By]" & _
             "  FROM " & AccIPLTable & " AS L "

  recs.open command1, iplDB, dbOpenDynaset

  FD1 = recs.Fields.Item(0)
  FD2 = recs.Fields.Item(1)
  FD3 = recs.Fields.Item(2)
  FD4 = recs.Fields.Item(3)
  FD5 = recs.Fields.Item(4)
  Console FD1 & ", " & FD2 & ", " & FD3 & ", " & FD4 & ", " & FD5

recs.close  

set recs = Nothing
```